# Find the sum of the series $1-\ln(2) +\frac{\ln(2)^2}{2!}-\frac{\ln(2)^3}{3!}+\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I can represent it as an infinite sum in the form: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\ln(2)^n}{n!}$, and I can use various series tests to prove it converges, but I'm unsure how to find the actual sum.

Comment: is this not $e^{-\ln 2} = \frac 12$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

use the $e^{-x}$
$$=e^{-\ln(2)}=1/2$$

Answer (score 0):

This series is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ when $x=-\ln 2$.  So first recall what $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is and then put $-\ln2$ in place of $x$.